# Select where the output stream of an XSLT template goes

Tags: xslt

Output generated by a template gets written to the standard output stream unless the template was called from inside <xsl:variable>, in which case the output become the value of that variable.

Is there a way to get both out of one template, that is, a way to direct some of the output to the standard output stream and direct some of the output back to the calling <xsl:variable>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get both out of one template, that is, a way to
>   direct some of the output to the standard output stream and direct
>   some of the output back to the calling `<xsl:variable>`?

Yes. Just capture the complete template output in a variable first. Then process this variable's content and output the wanted parts. Then create a new variable, whose content has the wanted parts from the complete template output that is captured in the first variable.

It would be good if you could provide a specific XML document and wanted result.

Comment: I was thinking of that. I was hoping there might be a more direct approach, just to avoid that extra task of unbundling what could be a non-trivial data structure. The template might generate, say, some HTML output, then a return flag for use by the caller, then more HTML output, then more return data, etc.

Comment: @JPM: The *good* way to organize such output: `<forVariable>results to be loaded into a variable</forVariable> <forOutput>results to be output</forOutput>`. Then the variable's `select = "$capturedVariable/forVariable/node()"`